# От какого глагола произошло отглагольное прилагательное "неотъемлемый" ?

Tags: словообразование

От какого глагола произошло отглагольное прилагательное "неотъемлемый" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был такой глагол - отъять (отнять). Неотъемлемый - то, что нельзя отнять (отъять- устаревшее)

Comment: Спасибо ;)

Comment: Чуть уточню формулировку. "Отъять" - не отдельный глагол, а лишь фонетический вариант современного "отнять".